# Intl.DateTimeFormat Localization does not work on Android in React Native

Tags: react-native

TLDR: **Intl.DateTimeFormat Localization does not appear to work on Android React Native.**

```
  "name": "react-native",
  "version": "0.59.8",
```

The following code works in IOS Simulator:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

function getSForLocale(locales) {
    return JSON.stringify(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(locales, {month: "long", day: "numeric"}).format(new Date()));
}

const LegoFigure = () => {
    console.log(`[BE TRANQUIL]`);

    return <View>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'}</Text>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{getSForLocale('ko-KR')}</Text>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{getSForLocale("fr")}</Text>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{getSForLocale("es")}</Text>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{getSForLocale("ru")}</Text>
        <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{getSForLocale("default")}</Text>
    </View>
};

export default LegoFigure;
```

**IOS Simulator:**

[image]

But Does not work on Android Physical Device:

**Android Physical Device:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Appears that Intl.DateTimeFormat Support was an issue that was resolved in Android SDK ~1 month ago (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-27890).  Realted to this issue.